# How to prevent Hibernate/JPA from translating column names in HQL queries?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I'm updating our applications from hibernate v5 to v6. This requires us to change our data access layer to use JPA queries instead of the hibernateTemplate ones we've had before (I know...).

An issue I'm running into is that the compiled SQL has automatically translated column names so filtering is a problem. For instance, I have a table "Schedule" with a primary key 'uuid' as well as another column called 'id'.

So a query like:

```
from Schedule where id = :scheduleId and sourceId = :sourceId"
```

Results in actual SQL like:

```
    select
        s1_0.uuid,
        s1_0.name,
        ...
        s1_0.id,
        s1_0.sourceId,
    from
        Schedule s1_0 
    where
        s1_0.uuid=? 
        and s1_0.sourceId=?
```

Where as I would expect it to look like:

```
    select
        s1_0.uuid,
        s1_0.name,
        ...
        s1_0.id,
        s1_0.sourceId,
    from
        Schedule s1_0 
    where
        s1_0.id=? 
        and s1_0.sourceId=?
```

As you can see the `id` filter is translated to the primary key column name. This does not happen if we filter for other columns such as `name`. Is there any way to prevent HQL/Hibernate/JPA from doing this? For multiple reasons, we do not want to change any column names so that's not really an option.

Comment: Is using JPA repository an option for you? It provides many auto-generated filter methods and has a solution for ambiguous field names. Using underscore.

Comment: Can you provide the declaration of `Schedule` entity?